# Why revision # different between show log and svn update?

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

When i take update on one svn folder it shows latest revision at which update is taken as `Completed At revision:116`

But when i do show log on that folder it shows latest revision number as `100` in history.

My question why both revision numbers are not in synch ?

For information :- when i execute below command to see if there is any change b/w revision 100 and 116, i see  diff.txt created with no content

`svn diff -r 100:116 > diff.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subversion revisions are global per repository

Log for any **subtree of repo** show only revisions, which affected this subtree (and ignore all outside tree)

---

### Explanation by example

```
\branches>svn up
Updating '.':
...
Updated to revision 5.
```

*Repository HEAD* is r5

```
branches>svn log -q
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | lazybadger | 2013-11-28 00:13:01 +0600 (Чт, 28 ноя 2013)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | www-data | 2013-11-27 18:13:32 +0600 (Ср, 27 ноя 2013)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but *latest commit into* `/branches` was only in r2

PS: You have to read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/), really

Comment: See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs, `Global Revision Numbers` topic

Comment: Thanks  Lazy Badger. So how can i know which repository revision 3,4 and 5 exists and who did those commits ?
Also when you say that `Subversion revisions are global per repository`  In your case repository is `branches`. Right ?
If there is no other revision checked in under that branch, revisions till what what repository it will display while update ?
Will it include revisions for `tag,branch and trunk` ?